# Can you claim $1+i>1$?

Tags: complex-numbers

The title says it all: I know you can claim $i+1>i$. But can you also claim $1+i >1$? If not why can't I?

Comment: What does $1+i>1$ mean?

Comment: A quick DuckDuckGo search yields [this PDF](https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~angell/articles/complexorder.pdf) document.

Comment: No, you can't claim $\;1+i>1\;$ .There does not exist any relation of order on $\;\Bbb C\;$ .In fact, there can't be such an order.

Comment: Actually, there could be an order relation on $\mathbb C$ (e.g., dictionary order), but it is not compatible with field operations

Comment: “I know you can claim “$1+i>i.$“ Not sure how you know this, if $i$ is the imaginary number. We generally don’t define $>$ on complex numbers, because any such definition is not useful, except in really narrow cases.

Comment: Simply put:  No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there is no way to "order" $\mathbb{C}$ in a way that is compatible with the operations of addition and multiplication that $\mathbb{C}$ is equipped with - $\mathbb{C}$ is not an ordered field with the usual operations. What this means in practice is that we cannot compare the sizes of complex quantities in a meaningful way using $<$ or $>$.

One way we commonly get around this problem is to instead consider the relative *magnitudes* of complex quantities. For example, $|1+i|=\sqrt{2}>1=|i|$, and $|1+i|=\sqrt{2}>1=|1|$. This is perfectly valid, because we have moved away from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, which is an ordered field and hence allows us to make these comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to extend $>$ to the complex numbers in such a way that the new relation is the same for the real numbers.

Define $a+bi>c+di$ to stand for $a>c$ or $a=c$ and $b>d$ (as customary, $a,b,c,d$ denote real numbers; “and” binds more strictly than “or”).

This can be easily proved to be a (strict) order relation: indeed it is false that $a+bi>a+bi$; transitivity is a simple case analysis.

With this relation it is true that $1+i>1$.

Unfortunately, you cannot claim that $z_1>z_2$ and $z_3>z_4$ implies $z_1+z_3>z_2+z_4$, nor that $z_1>z_2$ and $z>0$ implies $z_1z>z_2z$ (find counterexamples).

In more technical terms, $\mathbb{C}$ is not an ordered field with respect to this order relation. It is not an ordered field under *any* order relation. Indeed, in an ordered field one has $1>0$ and every nonzero square is $>0$. Since $i^2=-1$, we'd find $-1>0$, so $1-1>0+0$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

No, because that would imply that $i>0,$ which would imply that $i^2>0,$ or in other words that $$-1>0,$$ which is nonsense in our frame of ordering.